# Include Select inside pagination - bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to include a dropdown inside the bootstrap pagination.

http://jsfiddle.net/Z4dsD/6/

1. The dropdown is not aligned properly.
2. There is a gap between the Next & Prev buttons.

How can it be fixed.

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="pagination custom-pagination">
    <li><a href="#">First</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Prev</a></li>
    <li>
        <select class="form-control">
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
        </select>
    </li>
    <li style="display:inline-block;"><a href="#">Next</a></li>
    <li style="display:inline-block;"><a href="#">Last</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
.custom-pagination select {
    display:inline-block;
    width:85px;
    border-radius:0px;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Twitter bootstrap html select inside pagination component is offset and not aligned](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13617358/twitter-bootstrap-html-select-inside-pagination-component-is-offset-and-not-alig)

Answer (score 2):

Just add the following to your css of the select:

```
vertical-align: top;
```

This will align the `select` at the top level.

Also you need to add a `margin-left: -1px;` to align it properly with the other elements.

Also remove the `display: inline-block` style from the last 2 `li` elements and set the float of the select to left.

Working jsfiddle: [Select jsfidle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z4dsD/7/)